# Notification URL for PayPal IPN and recurring payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment, recurring-billing

I'm working on implementation of PayPal recurring payments, but I have some doubts.

The steps to create a recurring payment profile are:

1. Call SetExpressCheckout (with L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments)
2. Get the TOKEN
3. Call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile with the token and the billing frequency
4. Receive the response with the ID of the active profile.

If I set the notify URL (PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL) in SetExpressCheckout does PayPal IPN notify about recurring payment?

According to https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Recurring-payments-IPN/td-p/350104?profile.language=en CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile does not accept the notify URL but SetExpressCheckout does!

Answer (score 0):

The SEC call does indeed set your IPN. Remember, you're setting up everything with PayPal to process a payment (setting the stage, so to speak). So it makes sense that it, and it alone, would accept the IPN callback (I wouldn't want conflicting IPN URLs in the various calls afterwards)

I would still specify an IPN URL in your account just to be safe, but yes, if you provide an IPN callback you will get notifications sent to that callback.